# unexpected std::io_base::failure exception

Tags: c++, gcc, redhat

Take this simple program:

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in(".");
    int x;
    if (in)
        in >> x;
}
```

on Redhat 6, gcc 4.4.7 this runs without error

on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS , gcc 4.8.2 this runs without error

on Redhat 7, gcc 4.8.2 I get:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
>   what(): basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file
> Aborted (cored dumped)
> ```

I think this is related to:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53984

However, then I don't understand why it works on Ubuntu.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The difference isn't the compiler, the difference is the C++ library.  One of them has a buggy version of libstdc++, and the other has a working version of either libstdc++ or libc++ or another version.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested on my Trusty Tahr system. It blows up, just as on Red Hat. So it doesn't "work on Ubuntu".

To verify we're both getting the same results, here's the output of various commands I've used:

> ```
> cky@sunflower:~/tmp$ g++ -O2 -Wall -o test test.cc
> cky@sunflower:~/tmp$ ./test
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
>   what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file
> Aborted (core dumped)
> cky@sunflower:~/tmp$ gcc -v
> Using built-in specs.
> COLLECT_GCC=gcc
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
> Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
> Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
> Thread model: posix
> gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
> cky@sunflower:~/tmp$ dpkg -l libstdc++\*
> Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
> | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
> |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
> ||/ Name                                   Version                  Architecture             Description
> +++-======================================-========================-========================-==================================================================================
> ii  libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64                4.8.2-19ubuntu1          amd64                    GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
> un  libstdc++-4.8-doc                      <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> un  libstdc++-dev                          <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> un  libstdc++2.10-dev                      <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> un  libstdc++2.8-dev                       <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> un  libstdc++2.9-dev                       <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> un  libstdc++2.9-glibc2.1-dev              <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> un  libstdc++3.0-dev                       <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> ii  libstdc++6:amd64                       4.8.2-19ubuntu1          amd64                    GNU Standard C++ Library v3
> un  libstdc++6-4.8-dbg                     <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
> ```

Comment: Indeed - I was doing something stupid - it crashes on ubuntu as well.